# Testing a pre-loaded Laravel Eloquent model with a query scope

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I've recently started using Laravel's query scopes but one thing I feel like I'm missing is the ability to test an existing Eloquent object with a defined scope.

Say I've set up a 'published' scope for a **Post** model

```
public function scopePublished($q){ 
    return $q->whereNotNull('published_at');
}
```

If I have queried a list of all my Posts and want to put a symbol beside the published ones, ideally I want to write something like

```
if($post->isPublished()){ /* insert symbol */ }
```

...using the 'published' scope to test each post, is there any way I can do that (without running an additional query for each Post)?

Comment: There are cases where I don't have control of the query that would result in the list of Posts, so I'm unable to, for example, add an additional flag/column in the returned query result to indicate the published state.